# How to use ListView inside Navigation Drawer properly

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I've tried to make navigation drawer option menu similar to gmail app.

[image]

I've used two ListViews, one below the other. Soon I realized that that was the wrong approach cause if second lv has more items than it could fit on the page and user has to scroll, user would be able to scroll lv only and not entire drawer as in gmail app (effect can be seen on the screenshot). Then I figured, I'll just wrap them in the ScrollView and disable ListView scroll, right? Wrong. That collapsed ListViews.

So I'm wondering what is the right approach here? To use only one ListView with headers/footers in the drawer?

Comment: the easiest way would be to use a single scrollview and use textview and imageview for the UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To use only one ListView with headers/footers in the drawer?

IMHO, yes. You can use [my `MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) to stitch together your existing `ListAdapters`, plus headers, and put the `MergeAdapter` into the `ListView`. Or, just
roll your own `ListAdapter` that handles all the row types using `getViewTypeCount()`
and `getItemViewType()`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more so i can understand

Comment: @AndoMasahashi: Sorry, but I do not know what you need.

Comment: yes i m trying to Create Nav. menu Like Above image But i dont Know.

Comment: @AndoMasahashi: Implementing a navigation drawer is a very broad concept, too large for a Stack Overflow question. I recommend that you start with [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), then ask **specific** questions here on Stack Overflow in places where you need additional assistance.

Comment: sure First i m trying to understand Doc. then i will ask Specific ques.